# Pass checkbox values to php script page jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a following code it is getting the values of checked checkboxes and submit the data on button click.Pls look into the code and do let me where i am wrong.It is not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function(){
  $('#btnClick').click(function(){
    var val = [];
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
            url: 'server.php',
            type: "POST",
           data: ({val[i]}), ????
           success: function(data){

            }
        });


    });
  });
});
});
```

Comment: Wahts not working?  What error are you getting?  Why are you not simply submitting a form?  Try to give more information

Comment: data:$('form').serialize(); and remove each(func

Comment: i don't think that it is a good idea to send an ajax request for every checkbox separately.

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to use [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) , it's designed for exactly this kind of situation.

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnClick').click(function(){
   var val = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').serialize();
   $.ajax({
        url: 'server.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: val,
        success: function(data){

        }
    });

   });
 });
```

Also it's better to use `$(input[type=checkbox]:checked)` as the selector instead of `$(':checkbox:checked')`. From the jQuery docs:

> $(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('[type=checkbox]'). As with other
>   pseudo-class selectors (those that begin with a ":") it is recommended
>   to precede it with a tag name or some other selector; otherwise, the
>   universal selector ("*") is implied. In other words, the bare
>   $(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('*:checkbox'), so
>   $('input:checkbox') should be used instead.
>
> Because :checkbox is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS
>   specification, queries using :checkbox cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll()
>   method. For better performance in modern browsers, use
>   [type="checkbox"] instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Keep the ajax function outside the `each` loop.
- `$(function(){})` & `$(document).ready(function(){})` are one and the
  same. The former is a shorthand form.

  ```
  $(function(){
    var val[], i=0;
    $('#btnClick').click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
        val[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
      });
       $.ajax({
              url: 'server.php',
              type: "POST",
             data: {'checked_values':val},
             success: function(data){
                  // do something with returned data
              }
       });
    });

  });
  ```

In **server.php** page

```
$checked = $_POST['checked_values']; // will contain an array with checked values
// proceed to do something with $checked array
```